# How to pass `Chk` parameter to dotpay payments gateway in Django (Saleor)

Tags: python, django, saleor

I'm having having difficulties integrating dotpay payment gateway in saleor. I'm not sure how am I suppose to pass `Chk` parameter to dotpay.

Saleor is using django-payments for that: 
https://github.com/mirumee/django-payments/blob/master/payments/dotpay/forms.py

Dotpay docs:
https://ssl.dotpay.pl/s2/login/cloudfs1/magellan_media/common_file/dotpay_technical_manual_for_payments_implementation.pdf

So far I've got set up:

`PAYMENT_VARIANTS = { 
    'dotpay': ('payments.dotpay.DotpayProvider', { 
    'seller_id': '123', 
    'pin': '0000', 
    'lock': True, 
    'endpoint': 'https://ssl.dotpay.pl/test_payment/'})}`

and

`CHECKOUT_PAYMENT_CHOICES = [ ('default', 'Dotpay')]`

Comment: What do you have currently and what error are you retrieving?

Comment: I don't know how to pass this parameter. In dotpay logs I'm getting warnings:
`Required Chk obtained, but hash is not equal. Obtained Chk "None"`
`Required Chk obtained, but hash not equal. Obtained Chk "None", but expected Chk "75aafba7b49efaded94652b958bd6b31522826839553996604b7274d7c0492a1"`

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: I've set up `PAYMENT_VARIANTS = {
    'dotpay': ('payments.dotpay.DotpayProvider', {
        'seller_id': '123',
        'pin': '0000',
        'lock': True,
        'endpoint': 'https://ssl.dotpay.pl/test_payment/'})}`
and
`CHECKOUT_PAYMENT_CHOICES = [
    ('default', 'Dotpay')]`
When I'm trying to pay it redirects me to dotpay website with an error page to contact the store owner (myself).

Comment: Did you try to add chk to { “seller_id”: “123”, “pin”: ...

Comment: For every transaction it's a different hash generated here: https://github.com/mirumee/django-payments/blob/master/payments/dotpay/forms.py#L55
So how should I add it there?

Comment: Probably its the ProcessPaymentForm.signature I guess